# How to safely release resources allocated by constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

I use C function which should write text to the buffer allocated in the constructor. The problem is that I need to pass a string to the exception constructor, but after creating an exception, the memory allocated for the text is lost:

```
class SomeClass{
public:
    SomeClass(){
        //important code ->
        //...
        //<- important code

        if(0 != some_func_to_get_error()){
            int bufferLen = some_func_to_get_buff_len();
            char* bufferText = new char[bufferLen + 1];
            some_func_to_get_text(bufferText, bufferLen); //contains error text
            throw runtime_error(bufferText); //exit from constructor body
            //???
        }
    }
};
```

Now the text is lost somewhere. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: It isn't 'lost somewhere'. It is in the exception object. It should be released in its destructor, like any other resource acquired in a constructor.

Comment: @user207421 

however, you will have to write additional code to free the buffer. And if the user of the class does not know what to release it?

Comment: Is there a chance to use `std::string` instead?

Comment: @vahancho What construction needs to be written so that std :: string can work with this C function that works with char pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `runtime_error` in your code above refers to `std::runtime_error`? In this case, you can simply pass it an `std::string` and release the buffer. For example

```
int bufferLen = some_func_to_get_buff_len();
auto bufferText = std::unique_ptr<char[]> { new char[bufferLen + 1] };
some_func_to_get_text(bufferText.get(), bufferLen);
throw runtime_error({ bufferText.get(), bufferText.get() + bufferLen });
```

Alternatively, define your own exception type:

```
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <memory>


class my_error : public std::exception
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> msg;

public:
    my_error(std::unique_ptr<char[]>&& msg) noexcept
      : msg(std::move(msg))
    {
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return msg.get();
    }
};

…

int bufferLen = some_func_to_get_buff_len();
auto bufferText = std::unique_ptr<char[]> { new char[bufferLen + 1] };
some_func_to_get_text(bufferText.get(), bufferLen);
throw my_error(std::move(bufferText));
```

The main advantage of defining your own exception types is that it allows these types of errors to be handled separately. An additional bonus here would be that it also avoids copying the error string. Since exceptions should only happen in exceptional conditions, this shouldn't really be an issue though…

Answer (score 0):

Like most resource allocations in general, this case can be handled by using a container. The standard container for a string is `std::string`:

```
// add + 1 to bufferLen if using older standard than C++17
std::string bufferText(bufferLen);
```

When the string is destroyed, it will be deallocate its internal buffer.

Comment: Thank you. if I pass a pointer to a string of characters in the constructor std :: string, will it then free up memory in the destructor?

Comment: @sddvxd no. The string only copies the content of the pointed string. It does not take ownership of the pointer.